# Is there any backward compatibility of -p (--path) option in user/group commands?

Tags: useradd, passwd

I upgraded from SUSE SLES 11 to SLES 12 and found that some user/group commands (such as useradd, groupadd, groupmod ... ) are no longer accept -p (--path) option to specific the directory of passwd, shadow, group files.

In SLES 11, these commands are provided by pwdutils rpm. In the other hand, in SLES 12, they come from shadow rpm.

Does anyone know if there is a backward compatibility for this option? Or any others way by which I can do the same as -p option?

Answer (score 0):

The `--repository` or `--root` options may work as a alternative to the `-p` in SLES11.

```
   -r, --repository REPOSITORY
       change password in REPOSITORY repository

   -R, --root CHROOT_DIR
       Apply changes in the CHROOT_DIR directory and use the configuration
       files from the CHROOT_DIR directory.
```